# IIS/ASP.Net - basic authentication for one subdirectory

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis

I have some code code in App_Code that I want to expose via standard ASP pages/Forms authentication, as well as Web Services/Basic Authentication. Currently the folder layout is something like

```
MySite
  MyPage.aspx
  App_Code
     -> Mycode.cs
  Services
     -> MyWebService.asmx
```

I understand that if I want Basic authentication for the web service, and forms for the normal pages, I need to convert the "Services" directory to an application in IIS. But once that's done how to I add a reference to the Web Service back to all the code in the root App_Code folder? (without it, I just get missing reference errors when connecting to the asmx page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I've found to get this to work is to copy the App_Code & bin directories into the Services application. However, that causes problems for my app, and seems like a big hack to be honest.

I've decided to go a different route and write a single custom authentication module that combines Forms authentication and Basic authentication. That way I dont need to split the application, and I can have fine-grained control over which pages/directories I want to accept Basic, and which I want to accept Forms.

More info here: [Combining Forms Authentication and Basic Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830243/asp-net-combining-forms-authentication-and-basic-authentication)